# Java JNI - Is it possible to set an individual primitive array element in Java from C++

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Basically, I've been doing the following to retrieve Java Instance Fields (in this case, an int) and setting it to a new value like the following:

```
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "myVariable", "I");
env->SetIntField(obj, fid, (jint)2012);
```

However, I'd like to do this for an individual int element in a java int array such that:

```
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "myVariableArray", "[I");
PSUDOCODE: <"SET myVariableArray[0] = 2013" ... Is there a method for this?>
```

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer after looking through 15+ documents.

```
// Grab Fields
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "testField", "[I");

jintArray jary;
jary = (jintArray)env->GetObjectField(obj, fid);
jint *body = env->GetIntArrayElements(jary, 0);
body[0] = 3000;
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(jary, body, 0);
```

ReleaseIntArrayElements is key ... it returns a copy back to the java Instance Variable.

Comment: AND it releases the memory allocated by GetIntArrayElements().

Comment: Using `GetIntArrayElements` for accessing only one element is a waste. Use `SetIntArrayRegion` instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to change only one or few values I highly suggest to use `SetIntArrayRegion` as it avoids copying back and forth the whole array.

```
jintArray jMyArray = (jintArray)env->GetObjectField( obj, fid );
// jMyArray[0] = 2013
jint elements[] = { 2013 };
env->SetIntArrayRegion( jMyArray, 0, 1, elements );
```

for more JNI best practices refer to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/) article from IBM ;)